# how is the object created via System.out.println("Morning"), REACHABLE?

Tags: java, string

In the following statement

```
System.out.println("Morning");
```

the object containing the value "Morning" is created inside the String Pool. And we are not storing it's address explicitly. But still this object is reachable.

If we try to do anew `System.out.println("Morning");`  the JVM reuses the previously created object as it is existing in the string pool, it doesn't create a new object.

How does JVM keep track of this object , even though we are not storing it's address explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

`"Morning"` is a String Literal. All String Literals are added to the String constants pool when the class is being loaded.

> And we are not storing it's address explicitly

Whether we store the the reference or not has nothing to do with adding String literals to the constants pool. Everything within `""` goes there.

> But still this object is reachable.

Again, reachability has nothing to do with adding and retrieving from the String constants pool. How the JVM does it could be specific to the JVM but some JVMs could add Class constants Strings to the String constant pool during class loading.

Comment: what is "Class Constant Strings"? and how is it added to String Constant Pool  during the class loading?

Comment: Use `javap -v yourClassName` and you can see it for yourself. :) @AmirHasan